# How to copy files using apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class ReadFileExample {
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
    System.out.println("trying to copy file");
    CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();
    RouteBuilder route = new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("file://Users/aranja2/Documents/in/?fileName=sample.txt&charset=utf-8")
             .to("file://Users/aranja2/Documents/out/?fileName=sample.txt&charset=utf-8");
        }
    };
    ctx.addRoutes(route);
    ctx.start();
    // Maybe sleep a little here
    // Thread.sleep(4000);
    ctx.stop();
 }
}
```

I am using camel to copy files but it is not happening.I am using mac. The messages thrown are

> [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel
>   2.16.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting [main] INFO org.apache.camel.management.ManagedManagementStrategy - JMX is enabled
>   [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter -
>   Loaded 183 type converters [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRuntimeEndpointRegistry - Runtime
>   endpoint registry is in extended mode gathering usage statistics of
>   all incoming and outgoing endpoints (cache limit: 1000) [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - AllowUseOriginalMessage is
>   enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its
>   recommended to turn this option off as it may improve performance.
>   [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - StreamCaching
>   is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream
>   caching. See more details at
>   http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.FileEndpoint - Endpoint is configured
>   with noop=true so forcing endpoint to be idempotent as well [main]
>   INFO org.apache.camel.component.file.FileEndpoint - Using default
>   memory based idempotent repository with cache max size: 1000 [main]
>   INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: route1 started
>   and consuming from:
>   Endpoint[file://Users/aranja2/Documents/in/?noop=true] [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Total 1 routes, of which 1
>   is started. [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext -
>   Apache Camel 2.16.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.344 seconds
>   [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel
>   2.16.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Starting to graceful
>   shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds) [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 -
>   ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy -
>   Route: route1 shutdown complete, was consuming from:
>   Endpoint[file://Users/aranja2/Documents/in/?noop=true] [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Graceful shutdown of 1
>   routes completed in 0 seconds [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.16.2
>   (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 0.359 seconds [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.16.2
>   (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.007 seconds

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are reaching that directory on //Users/aranja2/Documents/in/?fileName=sample.txt? You rout seems ok. I've attached a sample project with a route copying from one directory to another. This ruse use the same parameter **fileName** as yours. You can run it just it **mvn camel:run**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9AooXd3hwFyWjZ4aEFRc0Znam8/view?usp=sharing

Cheers!